# "To be" as a state

Tags: verbs, translation, be

In Catalan and in Spanish we have two verbs: "ser" and "estar" . Both translate into English as "to be". One of the uses of "estar" is to say that something is in a certain state or place. So, for example, in Spanish we'd say: "la belleza a menudo ESTÁ donde menos te lo esperas", which translates into "beauty IS often where you don't expect". My problem here is that I feel something is missing in the English translation: because of using "often", I feel like I should put an adjective or something describing a state after it. So for example I'd say "is often present where....". My question is: is the first translation correct? Or is it necessary to put an extra verb to say that beauty "is located" to a place? In Spanish, "estar" already contains this meaning, hence my doubts.

Comment: I think I would translate that as *"Beauty is often **found** where you expect it the least"*.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what exactly the Spanish verbs have to do with this. _Be_ in English carries the meaning of both Spanish verbs, and your translation is fine – there doesn’t have to be an adjective after _be_ for it to mean the same as _estar_. Would you feel like you had to add something in in other senses, like _está bien_ or _estoy cansado_? Those would also just be “it’s okay” and “I’m tired”. [Also note that _located_, _situated_, _present_, etc., aren’t verbs in a context like this, but adjectives.]

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, indeed I wouldn't add anything after "estar" in Spanish, but sometimes I feel like missing something when I use "to be" in a "plain" mode. It's funny actually, because non-Spanish speakers have the opposite problem when they learn Spanish: how to make the difference between "ser" and "estar" :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your solutions are correct, and the choice will depend on what kind of tone the speaker wants to set: More formal ... or more casual?

*Beauty's in the eye of the beholder* is something I might say to my girlfriend when she says I bought an ugly lamp. :-) So that IS is *very* casual.

One of the lame things about (American) English is that we use is / to-be all the freaking time. We sound pretty generic when we talk, compared to say, Germans. There, yes, they'd more frequently use *sich befinden* to say where something "is".

Comment: But we also do that when we say something like "Starfish are found in the sea".